# How do I implement NextAuth/Nextjs's authentication and redirect with separate backend

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have a backend with python that handles authentication already.
here is the auth urls

```
path('register',Register.as_view(), name='register'),
path('login',Login.as_view(), name='login'),
path('login/google',GoogleLoginApi.as_view(), name='login-google'),
```

- the `login` view accepts POST method (username and password) and will return `access_token` along with `refresh_token` and user information
- the `login/google` view accepts POST method (code response from Google) and will return `access_token` along with `refresh_token` and user information.

I've been using ReactJS for all client side rendering only. I used to store that accesstoken in localstorage for authentication and pages authorization (I know it's kinda messed up).

I want to learn more about SSG and SSR (NextJS). Then it comes a problem, how do I handle authentication and restricted pages in NextJS (SSR and SSG pages).

That's when I heard that NextAuth handles it out of the box easily.
after a while watching tutorials of NextAuth. Then more problems appear....

I see a lot of people using NextAuth while they're using the APIs provided by nextJs , like using prisma.

My question is: should I use NextAuth or is there other way?

If NextAuth is the preferred way, how do I handle the `CredentialProvider` and `GoogleProvider`?

If no, what kind of solutions are there for production ready systems?
Where/how do I store the session for SSR, SSG ? How do I access the session for SSR, SSG pages?

How do I handle restricted pages? How do you people handle this in production?

Can I see some of your repository that handles this

Thanks

What I tried is a ReactJS solution without SSR or SSG, like using "@react-oauth/google"; and I want to know what kind of approach for NextJS based app